How do I set the username and password for the HiveMQ UI using config.xml in 4.x?
I have the following...
<control-center>
  <users>
    <user>
      <name>admin</name>
      <password>7ca94b7c56a07d5a65383a7692f3811a25f6ce67ef648e4ceec750beb1dc43bb</password>
    </user>
  </users>
</control-center>

The idea being it should be admin as the username and TestPassword as the password. I get the hash via
me@yoda:~$ echo -n adminTestPassword | sha256sum
7ca94b7c56a07d5a65383a7692f3811a25f6ce67ef648e4ceec750beb1dc43bb  -

But when I restart the server the web ui (8080) still uses admin hivemq

What am I missing?
Docs are here

It seems the issue is without disabling the default user like...
<default-user-enabled>false</default-user-enabled>

you can't use the username admin I changed to adminUser and everything worked fine.

That's absolutely correct!
In order to use only newly created credentials, the tag  must be set to false within the Control Center config tag - the specifics on this can be found in the HiveMQ Control Center documentation here :
https://docs.hivemq.com/hivemq/latest/control-center/configuration.html#user-configuration

Feel free to let us know if you have any additional questions either here, or on the HiveMQ Community Forum - we are always happy
Best,
Aaron from the HiveMQ Team
